# Ler objetos salvos em arquivo.dat

Tags: c++, arquivo

Como devo proceder para que a função de leitura possa ler o `arquivo.dat` sempre que início o programa?
estou gravando objetos em um arquivo, e preciso lê-los sempre que o programa se inicia.

Problema: estou tendo problemas de falha de segmentação ao tentar ler estes dados já salvos.

```
void DataManip::DataManipWrite(DateAdress *writer) {

    ofstream ObjectWriter;
    ObjectWriter.open("dbaddress.dat", ios::binary);    
    ObjectWriter.write((char *)&writer, sizeof(writer));
    ObjectWriter.close();

}

void DataManip::DataManipRead(DateAdress *reader) {

    ifstream ObjectReader;
    ObjectReader.open("dbaddress.dat", ios::binary);    
    ObjectReader.read((char *)&reader, sizeof(reader));
    ObjectReader.close();

}
```

Comment: O problema não é tão simples e você não deu informações precisas, então eu dei uma resposta que pode ajudar a achar o caminho mas não garanto que ela seja a solução definitiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode gravar objetos e depois lê-los para a memória. Você precisa serializá-los.

De fato você está tentando fazer uma serialização quando usa o *cast* `(char *)` mas não dá o resultado que você espera.

Em geral você deveria gravar esses dados como texto. Não que não possa ser binário, mas você terá que criar um formato para esse binário. Não é só jogar qualquer informação lá. No texto também precisa de um formato mas aí é mais fácil porque tem alguns óbvios e simples de manipular.

Só porque um arquivo é considerado binário não quer dizer que você pode jogar código binário ou informação direta da memória. Esse binário quer dizer que os dados ali devem ser tratados *byte* a *byte* e não considerar existir nada específico nele. Ele deve ser tratado como uma sequência de *bytes* e o programa deve saber como tratá-las.

Em um arquivo texto há algumas suposições como por exemplo a existência de quebra de linha.

Como o C++ não tem uma funcionalidade própria em sua biblioteca que facilite a serialização. Existem bibliotecas de terceiros para isto.

A primeira recomendação que faço é gravar em arquivo texto. A não ser que realmente precisa que seja binário e quer arcar com a complexidade de fazer isto.

A segunda é preparar uma forma se serialização para gravar e deserialização após ler.

A primeira pegará cada um dos membros do tipo `DateAdress` e transformará em um texto sequencial que possa ser gravado no arquivo. Note que pode ser necessário fazer algumas conversões em tipos numéricos e principalmente em tipos que na verdade sejam ponteiros. Você não pode gravar o ponteiro, terá que gravar o dado que o ponteiro aponta (isto inclui um processo recursivo) ou alguma identificação para que depois uma informação seja associada a outra corretamente (isto não é fácil fazer corretamente).

Quando ler esses dados serializados no arquivo terá que fazer o processo inverso, interpretar cada informação constante no texto de acordo com seu tamanho ou através de marcadores especiais (se manter a ordem dos campos), ou que sabe identificadores para cada campo (aí não precisa manter a ordem, um exemplo disto é o formato de JSON). Pegando cada informação individualmente pode colocar no devido membro do tipo `DateAdress`, fazendo as devidas conversões.

É complicado? É. Tem um jeito melhor? Eu desconheço.

Só quero reforçar que eventualmente um arquivo binário pode ser mais útil, a grande diferença é que você vai ter que entender o conteúdo sem nenhum ajuda do padrão adotado em textos.

O erro ocorre porque no fundo você está jogando sujeira na memória.

O *cast* que você usou não é recomendado em C++. Não estou dizendo que vai funcionar mas ajudaria se tivesse feito `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&writer)`. Não tenho como testar aqui mas não sei se o mesmo se aplicaria para o `reader`. Isso é só uma ideia.

Não estou dizendo que o que está fazendo não pode funcionar, apenas que é uma bela de uma gambiarra. Vou até sugerir uma mudança que talvez resolva sua situação se o tipo `DateAdress` for simples o suficiente. Note que pode funcionar mas é uma solução frágil.

Leia os dados individualmente ao invés de ler a estrutura toda:

```
ObjectReader.read((char *)&reader.campo1, sizeof(reader.campo1));
ObjectReader.read((char *)&reader.campo2, sizeof(reader.campo2));
ObjectReader.read((char *)&reader.campo3, sizeof(reader.campo3));
```

Como não sei a composição do tipo, chutei três nomes para os campos.

Mas também para funcionar talvez seja necessário "compactar" a estrutura, o que nem sempre é desejável. Nunca o fiz mas sei que é precisa usar um `#pragma`:

GCC:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) nome { ... };
```

Microsoft:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct nome { ... };
#pragma pack(pop)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Pack.c).

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pelas informações! 
Esse método que usei não funcionara com o tipo de projeto que estou fazendo, eu optei em manter o objeto DateAdress, porém na escrita estou gravando como ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary, em um arquivo mesmo,  os arquivos serão salvos em um diretorio DATA, pois preciso fazer pesquisas atraves de endereços fornecidos pelo usuario.
mais uma vez muito obrigado!

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer com isto. Ou entendi e acho que agora está mais claro que você está no caminho errado.

Comment: vou postar como estou trabalhando agora com a nova versão do projeto.

Answer (score 0):

O erro é que você não está gravando um objeto do tipo `DateAddress` no arquivo, mas na verdade um ponteiro para um `DateAddress`.

Seu arquivo `.dat` está ficando algo do tipo:

```
A4 FE 22 00
```

4 bytes que representam apenas um ponteiro para um `DateAddress`, ou seja a variável local `writer`.

Então nas linhas onde tem:

```
ObjectWriter.write((char *)&writer, sizeof(writer));
ObjectReader.read((char *)&reader, sizeof(reader));
```

Deveria ser:

```
ObjectWriter.write((char *)writer, sizeof(DateAddress));
ObjectReader.read((char *)reader, sizeof(DateAddress));
```

Ainda sim o código acima faz uma leitura/escrita muito "cega" de dados do arquivo, creio que seria mais correto ler/escrever membro por membro da classe.

Comment: o problema e que meu programa tentava lêr algo que não estava mais na memoria, e eu ja sabia que isso estava acontecendo só queria ver se tinha alguma solução para fazer tal coisa.

Comment: Exatamente, porque você estava gravando um ponteiro e não o `DateAddress` de verdade, quando você lia de volta o ponteiro vinha inválido, pois o mesmo pertencia a execução anterior do programa e que já havia sido destruído.

Comment: exatamente camarada !  
hehehee.

Answer (score 0):

```
void DataManip::DataManipWrite(DateAdress *writer) {

#define LENGTH 1024
char Directory[LENGTH] = {"Data/"}; 

    ofstream ObjectWriter;
    strcat(Directory, writer->getFamily()); strcat(Directory,".dat");
    ObjectWriter.open(Directory, ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);    
    ObjectWriter << "#------------------------------#"<< endl;
    ObjectWriter << "Bairro: " << writer->getBairro() << endl;
    ObjectWriter << "Rua: " << writer->getRua() << endl;
    ObjectWriter << "Telefone: " << writer->getTelefone() << endl;
    ObjectWriter << "Numero: " << writer->getNumero() << endl;
    ObjectWriter << "#------------------------------#\n"<< endl;

    ObjectWriter.close();

}

void DataManip::DataManipRead(char Directory[]) {
    string line_text;
    ifstream ObjectReader;
    strcat(Directory,".dat");
    ObjectReader.open(Directory, ios::in | ios::binary);

    if(ObjectReader.is_open() ) {
        while(getline(ObjectReader, line_text)) {
            cout << line_text << endl;
        }

    }   

    ObjectReader.close();

}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações pessoal!
para o meu projeto, eu optei por este método.

Comment: Ou seja, você fez o que eu te falei?

Comment: eu ja tinha esta versão do projeto mais basicamente sim por isso votei em sua resposta :P, eu só queria saber se existia algum jeito de lêr objetos igual fazemos com struct no C , para este tipo de projeto não iria se adequar.

Comment: Isso é a sua solução ou um complemento da pergunta?

Comment: uma solução que eu já tinha para o meu projeto.