# Utilidade do #pragma

Tags: c, c++

Vários códigos em C/C++ possuem a palavra **pragma**. Dependendo do jeito que que é implementada tem uma função diferente.

**#pragma once**

**#pragma pack()**

**#pragma comment(xx, "")**

> Para qual finalidade o **pragma** foi feito?
>
> Qual é a sua função na linguagem?
>
> Com o *pragma comment*, é possível inserir credenciais no sistema?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Começo falar disso em [Em C/C++, para que servem as diretivas de compilação? Quando devo utilizá-las?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90571/101).

Todos esses são usados pelo compilador da Microsoft, até onde sei exclusivamente, portanto não portáveis.

Todas podem ser vistas na [documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160).

## Padding

Falo especificamente de [`pragma pack`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160) em [Ler objetos salvos em arquivo.dat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45097/101), [Como funciona o "padding" do C/C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50614/101) e [Por que o tamanho de uma struct não é a soma dos tamanhos de suas variáveis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125057/101).

Ele serve para reduzir o tamanho de uma estrutura e não fazer alinhamento. Útil em bem raras situações.

## Include sem repetir

O [`pragma once`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160) usado para impedir que um `include` seja colocado novamente onde já foi incluso uma vez durante aquela unidade de compilação. A forma mais portável de fazer isso é com definição de variáveis indicativas que já foi incluso. Dei [exemplo disso em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124398/101).

Sem ele haveria desperdício na compilação tendo que ficar analisando o que já havia sido feito.

## Comentários para o *linker*

O [`pragma comment`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160) é usado para incluir um comentário no código objeto gerado pelo compilador e que possivelmente será lido pelo *linker* para fazer alguma coisa específica. Um exemplo:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "nomeDaBiblioteca")
```

Isso indica que a biblioteca é necessária para funcionar.

Poderia ser uma opção de *linkedição* que o compilador vai fazer. Ou ainda fazer algum tipo de assinatura no código, algo como:

```
#pragma comment(user, "texto aqui")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Pragma.c).

Comment: como posso estar fazendo uma assinatura?

Comment: Nunca fiz, acredito que seria algo assim `#pragma comment(user, "texto aqui")`.

Answer (score 5):

Pragmas são "diretivas" para o compilador, que afetam o processo de compilação.

O pragma "once" normalmente (sempre ?) é utilizado no início de um arquivo .h que vai ser incluído em outros arquivos fonte .c ou .cpp (ou mesmo outros .h). Este pragma instrui o compilador a ler este arquivo apenas uma vez, mesmo que o fluxo de compilação de um fonte implique sua leitura mais de uma vez.

Por exemplo:

1. existe um arquivo include "a.h", com o pragma "once" na primeira linha
2. existe um arquivo include "b.h" que inclui "a.h"
3. existe um arquivo include "c.h" que inclui "a.h"
4. existe um arquivo "p.c" que inclui "b.h" e "c.h"

O compilador, ler "p.c", inclui (lê) "b.h", e ao ler "b.h" também inclui "a.h". Em seguida o compilador (ainda processando "p.c") inclui "c.h" e descobre que deveria incluir "a.h", mas como "a.h" já foi incluído em "b.h", não é feita uma nova inclusão de "a.h".

O pragma "pack" controla o alinhamento de membros de uma estrutura. Normalmente, por razoes de eficiência uma struct assim:

```
struct
{
   char c;
   int  i;
} s;
```

possui um "buraco" de 3 bytes entre "c" e "i", para "alinhar" o endereço de "i" em um endereço múltiplo de 4, pois normalmente é mais eficiente para o processador acessar um "int" que possua um endereço multiplo de 4.

Usando um pragma pack(1), por exemplo, podemos evitar a ocorrência desses "buracos" ao custo de uma provável ineficiência no acesso ao membro "i" da estrutura.

```
#pragma pack(1) // força alinhamento de 1
struct
{
   char c;
   int  i;
} s;
#pragma pack() // volta o alinhamento default
```

O pragma "comment" se não me engano embute strings no código executável, mas não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 1):

**Pragmas** são diretiva, que é uma construção de algumas linguagens de programação que especifica como o compilador ou montador deve processar o código fonte.

Utilizado em linguagens de programação (`C` e `C++`), `#pragma once` é uma diretiva não-padrão, indica que o arquivo onde ele reside será ignorado se incluído várias vezes. Assim, uma vez `#pragma`, tem a mesma finalidade como `#include` (guarda), mas com várias vantagens, incluindo:

- menos códigos
- evitar conflitos de nomes
- aumento na velocidade de compilação.

Esta diretiva é mais útil para programas que são excepcionalmente grandes ou que precisam tirar vantagens das capacidades de um compilador particular.

O `pragma comment` coloca um registro de comentário em um arquivo de objeto ou executável. O comentário pode ser lido pelo *linker* quando ele processa arquivos de objeto.

Referência:

- [Pragma Directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805(VS.71).aspx)