# O que é #pragma c#

Tags: c#

Ao dar manutenção em um código de um web service me deparei com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
```

Ao buscar seu significado, não encontrei nada em português que fosse de fácil acesso.

**Questão**

O que é `#pragma` ? E quando deve ser utilizado ?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155564/utilidade-do-pragma/155570?s=1|2.5521#155570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `#pragma` serve para passar instruções especificas para o compilador

Para usar deve informar da seguinte maneira `#pragma nome-configuracao argumentos`

No exemplo a seguir é desabilidado os warnings parao trecho de código de teste, pode notar que existe uma variavel que é declarada e não é utilizada, isto naturalmente exibiria um warning na compilação, mas como desabilitamos o mesmo não será exibido

```
#pragma warning disable warning-list  
public void teste(){
    string naoUtiliza = "Teste";
    return "Teste";
}
#pragma warning restore warning-list
```

Answer (score 4):

O #pragma fornece ao compilador instruções especiais para a compilação do arquivo no qual ele é exibido. O compilador deve dar suporte às instruções. Em outras palavras, não é possível usar #pragma para criar instruções personalizadas de pré-processamento. O compilador Microsoft C# dá suporte a estas duas #pragma instruções:

```
#pragma warning
#pragma checksum
```