# Warnings interferem no programa?

Tags: c

Estou a realizar o seguinte exercício:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após algumas tentativas cheguei ao seguinte código final:

```
int proximo_da_media(int *vec, int dim){
 int i, *pos;
 float media, soma=0, diferenca;
 pos=vec; //inicializar ponteiro
  for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    soma+=*(vec+i);  //faz a soma de todos os numeors
 media=0.5+(soma/dim); //faz a media e soma 0.5,como a seguir faz subtração com um int se a media tiver a parte decimal igual ou superior a 0.5 arredonda para cima se não mantem o int original
 diferenca=abs((*vec)-media); //calcula a diferença entre a media e o primeiro valor do vetor em valor absoluto
  for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
    if(abs(*(vec+i)-media)<diferenca){ //se o valor absoluto entre a media e vec[i] for menor que a diferenca anterior então foi descoberto um numero mais proximo da media logo atualizo a diferenca e o ponteiro para o numero encontrado
        diferenca=abs(*(vec+i)-media);
        pos=vec+i;
    }
}
return pos;}

int main(){
 int tabela[10]={20,30,43,5,400,1999,9,360,3,8},*posicao;
 posicao=proximo_da_media(tabela,10);
 printf("O endreco do ponteiro que aponta para o numero mais proximo da media e o %p e tem o valor %d\n",posicao,*posicao);}
```

Com o vetor inserido no código a soma de todos os numeros é de 2877 , fazendo a media (2877/10) chegamos ao resultado de 287,7 que arredonda para 288, sendo 360 o número mais próximo da media.

Fiz alguns testes e o programa tem corrido como esperado, para este exemplo também correu bem,obtive o seguinte output:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apesar de executar como esperado tenho 2 warnings e não sei se devo alterar algo no código, os warnings são os seguintes:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se o algoritmo está correto e se devo alterar algo no código.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim.

E não.

Ou seja, potencialmente interfere. Você aceita algo que pode ou não dar problema?

O erro certamente dará problema. O compilador tem, e muitas pessoas usam, opção que trata os *warnings* como erros, e geralmente é recomendado fazer assim mesmo.

Eu ouço programadores inexperientes considerarem que eles não causam mal. Até o dia que causa e a pessoa fica sem saber o que fazer. E pior, muitos dos males possíveis não são identificáveis.

Tenha como regra eliminar todos os *warnings*. Se tiver algum raro caso que não tem nada em código normal que possa eliminar um deles, e é muito raro isto ocorrer, use um [`#pragma`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155564/101) para silenciar o compilador e tornar evidente que ali faz algo diferente.

A chance desses *warnings* causarem problema é grande.

O primeiro praticamente deveria ser um erro. Se você quer retornar um ponteiro, faça o tipo da função ser um ponteiro e depois use o resultado de forma adequada. De fato, pelo que entendi do código, é um erro retornar `int`, deveria ser um `int *`.

O segundo parece ser consequência do primeiro erro e se consertá-lo deve eliminar o segundo *warning*.

Achei o código confuso, ele pode ser mais simples que isto, acho que assim fica melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *proximo_da_media(int *vec, int size) {
    int *pos = vec;
    float soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) soma += pos[i];
    float media = soma / size + 0.5f;
    float diferenca = abs(*pos - media);
    for (int i = 0; i < size;i++) {
        if (abs(pos[i] - media) < diferenca) {
            diferenca = abs(pos[i] - media);
            vec = &pos[i];
        }
    }
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    int tabela[10] = {20, 30, 43, 5, 400, 1999, 9, 360, 3, 8};
    int *posicao = proximo_da_media(tabela, 10);
    printf("O endreco do ponteiro que aponta para o numero mais proximo da media e o %p e tem o valor %d\n", (void *)posicao, *posicao);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DZU2fC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pnstiwll-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Average2.c).

Não analisei se o código faz o que espera.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, alterei o int para int* e os warnings desapareceram, entretanto também comentei o meu código original para mais fácil compreensão , realmente o seu é mais legível, vou fazer algumas alterações mas como comecei a aprender ponteiros há pouco tempo fui aconselhado a usar apenas ponteiros nos meus programas para me acostumar e entender bem a manipulação de ponteiros

Comment: Não sei se foi um bom conselho.

Comment: ao longo destes dias cometi vários erros na manipulação dos ponteiros que não voltarei a cometer, acho que me ajudou nesse aspecto

Comment: E provavelmente pegou vários vícios... :)

Answer (score 1):

A warning já disse qual o problema, você definiu o tipo de retorno da função como um int, mas está tentando retornar um ponteiro para int, mude de `int proximo_da_media(int *vec, int dim)` para `int* proximo_da_media(int *vec, int dim)` e a mensagem sumirá.
Nesse caso apareceu essa warning, pois não é um erro de sintaxe e sim de semântica estática, e em C ponteiros tem o tamanho de um int, em sistemas 64bits um int vale 4 bytes e um ponteiro possui também 4 bytes e o que a sua função está retornando é o valor correspondente a posição de memória onde pos está apontando.

Comment: Obrigado, alterei a declaração da função e os dois warnings desapareceram!